# Filter with forEach returns an empty array instead of filtered values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array of objects according to its rate but in result  I get an empty array. I know that forEach doesn't return any values so I tried to use some() method but still got the same result.I thought that mapping would return an array of filtered objects but it returns undefined.
My code is like the following:

```
let ratings = ['4', '1'];
let objects = [{ rate: 1 }, { rate: 4.5 }, { rate: 3.4 }];
let filtered = objects.filter((obj) => {
  ratings.forEach((rating) => {
    if (Math.round(obj.rate) < Number(rating)) {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Should I use map instead of forEach to solve the issue or is there another problem here?

Comment: You are not returning anything in filter. The scope of your return is inside the forEach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't care about the return value of the function you pass it.

You'll maybe want [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the inner loop instead; it will return `true` as soon as the function you pass it returns a truthy value, and `false` if it never does:

```
let ratings = ['4', '1'];
let objects = [{ rate: 1 }, { rate: 4.5 }, { rate: 3.4 }];
let filtered = objects.filter((obj) => {
  return ratings.some((rating) => {
    return (Math.round(obj.rate) < Number(rating));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just `return` a value within a `forEach` loop (and you never return `false` anyway).

Also there's no need to convert the string to numbers multiple times on every loop, just do that once before you being looping. I assume you are receiving the data this way from some source and you can't just get an array of numbers to begin with.

Using `.some()` will help narrow things down easier than using an inner loop.

```js
let ratings = ['4', '1'];
let objects = [{ rate: 1 }, { rate: 4.5 }, { rate: 3.4 }];

//----------
let ratingsAsNum = ratings.map(Number);
let filtered = objects.filter((obj) =>
  ratingsAsNum.some(r => Math.round(obj.rate) < r)
);

console.log(filtered)
```